# Aurelia repeat.for generating an extra element

Tags: aurelia

**Problem**
I have a `repeat.for` in my html markup bound to an array on my viewmodel.  The array only has one element.  However, the generation of the HTML always produces one extra `undefined` element.

This behavior only appears in one section of my code which makes it very hard to duplicate -- `repeat.for` is working everywhere else in my code.

**Proof**
So before you label me crazy and try to insist that my array must have more items than I think, have a look at my code and at the output from the Aurelia Inspector.

**client.js**

```
export class Client {
   months = []

   activate(id) {
      ...
      this.loadData()
   }

   loadData(){
      this.months.push("Item1")
    }
```

**client.html**

```
<section class="scrollable">
    ${months.length}
    <div repeat.for="month of months">
       Index = ${$index}
    </div>
</section>
```

My output looks like this:

```
1
Index = 0
Index = 1
```

If I use Aurelia Inspector, here is what I see:

**Inspecting '1'** = ${months.length}

[image]

**Inspecting 'Index = 0'** = ${$index}

[image]

**Inspecting 'Index = 1'** = ${$index}

[image]

Has anyone seen similar behavior with repeat.for?  Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If `months` is empty, does it still render an extra elem?

Comment: No.  I commented out the `this.months.push("Item1")` line and my output is simply `0` (i.e. the length of the array).

Comment: Following up on that, I decided to add two items instead of one.  Now in my output, I get four `Index =` elements.

Comment: this is probably because you have `aurelia-binding` twice in your bundle (may be caused due to old plugins or similar reasons) . try updating to latest aurelia (best if you create a new aurelia app using the cli and copy your src folder)

Comment: more on that [here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/830) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/580) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/902)

Comment: @avrahamcool Thanks for the links!  Based on the comment by StrahilKazlachev on [this thread](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/580), I switched from using `this.months.push()` to using a temporary array and setting `this.months = temparray`.  That seems to resolve the problem for me.

Comment: although you can fix the symptom in that way - you still have `aurelia-binding` twice in your bundle - I would fix that instead..